# ImageMagick getImageLength() not found

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Initially, I used getImageSize but an error message informed me it was deprecated, and to use getImageLength instead. Then I get this error.

```
Call to undefined method Imagick::getImageLength()
```

I'm using imagick 3.01 and ImageMagick 6.2.8.0 on CentOS 5.8. I upgraded imagick to the 3.1 RC2, but the error persisted. I reinstalled ImageMagick and ImageMagick-devel and still no luck. I used yum to install ImageMagick, and then pecl to install imagick.

Any advice? Thanks.

Pastebin data from get_class_methods dump

http://pastebin.com/MUkDBJpY

Version info is below

```
array(2) {
  ["versionNumber"]=>
  int(1576)
  ["versionString"]=>
  string(79) "ImageMagick 6.2.8 05/07/12 Q16 file:/usr/share/ImageMagick-       6.2.8/doc/index.html"
}
```

Comment: What you used looks legit. Can you var_dump get_class_methods on your Imagick object please and paste bin your dump?

Comment: @Layke I did as you asked, and edited my post with the info. As expected, getImageLength isn't there, but getImageSize is, though it just calls up a deprecated warning when used.

Comment: Can you call $im->getversion() as well. (I realise you already provided the version you have installed, but just to be sure)

Comment: @Layke I edited my post with the version info. It only lists the ImageMagick version, which I'm sure is fine since identify brings me all the info I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure. The best I can think of now is to include information in your question of how you installed Imagic, perhaps something will strike out as being wrong.

Comment: @Layke Ah. Thanks anyways. I'll just use a workaround hack for now

Comment: Experiencing the exact same issue myself. Installed in the same way and everything works fine apart from getimagelength. Ironically, trying to use getimagesize will throw an error that it's deprecated and to use getimagelength. What was your workaround/fix?

Comment: @Chris It's been a while and I'm not completely sure, but I either wrote my own version or switched so something else. I would recommend seeing if you can upgrade to a newer version of Imagemagick.

Comment: @saccharine thanks, yes strange that this still presists after this much time. The version of Imagick is also the current stable (3.1.2) - so over a whole version release since the getImageLength method should have been implemented (2.0.0)